# How to make prisma fail in CI on data loss

Tags: prisma

In my CI, I want to apply the latest changes to my prisma schema and make sure they don't cause data loss.

It seems the two options are

- run `prisma migrate deploy`, which will accept data loss
- run `prisma migrate dev`, which will ask if you want to accept data loss, but this doesn't work in CI.

Is there a third option that just terminates with a non-zero exit code if there is a possibility of data loss?